# Pi-zero-w HID keyboard layout

Tags: usb, pi-zero-w

I'm setting up my pi0 as HID Keyboard. I've followed this link [Pi0 libcomposite gadget](http://isticktoit.net/?p=1383).

Every thing works fine, the pi is well recognized as USB Keyboard

```
$ dmesg
[ +16,318525] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[  +0,093215] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0104
[  +0,000003] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0,000001] usb 1-1.3: Product: hid3myPi
[  +0,000001] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: sk4mi
[  +0,000001] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 1049799107101100
[  +0,001447] input: sk4mi hid3myPi as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:1D6B:0104.0004/input/input15
[  +0,053447] hid-generic 0003:1D6B:0104.0004: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [sk4mi hid3myPi] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3/input0
```

with lsusb:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1d6b:0104 Linux Foundation Multifunction Composite Gadget
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0104 Multifunction Composite Gadget
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 sk4mi
  iProduct                2 hid3myPi
  iSerial                 3 1049799107101100
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           41
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 Config 1 : test
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              250mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              5 HID Interface
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.01
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      63
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               4
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               4
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

But now there is a little problem: when i send keystrokes to the host, the layout keyboard of HID device is wrong.

Per example, when i want to send the <kbd>a</kbd> char, i send:

```
echo -ne "\0\0\x4\0\0\0\0\0" > /dev/hidg0 #press a
echo -ne "\0\0\x0\0\0\0\0\0" > /dev/hidg0 #release key
```

But it's a <kbd>q</kbd> on the screen. So the device is configured as qwerty keyboard, but i want to send in azerty mode.

my script to initiate pi0 as HID device:

```
# load libcomposite module
modprobe libcomposite
# create gadget
cd /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/
mkdir -p hidzero
cd hidzero
echo 0x1d6b > idVendor
echo 0x0104 > idProduct
echo 0x0100 > bcdDevice
echo 0x0200 > bcdUSB
echo 8      > bCountryCode

mkdir -p strings/0x409
echo "1049799107101100" > strings/0x409/serialnumber
echo "sk4mi" > strings/0x409/manufacturer
echo "hid3myPi" > strings/0x409/product
mkdir -p configs/c.1/strings/0x409
echo "Config 1 : test" > configs/c.1/strings/0x409/configuration
echo 250 > configs/c.1/MaxPower

#-------------------
#functions here:
# ------------------

#hid conf
mkdir -p functions/hid.usb0
echo 1 > functions/hid.usb0/protocol
echo 1 > functions/hid.usb0/subclass
echo 8 > functions/hid.usb0/report_length
bash -c 'echo -ne \\x05\\x01\\x09\\x06\\xa1\\x01\\x05\\x07\\x19\\xe0\\x29\\xe7\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x01\\x75\\x01\\x95\\x08\\x81\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x08\\x81\\x03\\x95\\x05\\x75\\x01\\x05\\x08\\x19\\x01\\x29\\x05\\x91\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x03\\x91\\x03\\x95\\x06\\x75\\x08\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x65\\x05\\x07\\x19\\x00\\x29\\x65\\x81\\x00\\xc0  > functions/hid.usb0/report_desc'
ln -s functions/hid.usb0 configs/c.1/

#end functions

ls /sys/class/udc > UDC
```

I try to change the value of bCountryCode, but it don't take effect as we can see on lsusb result...

Anyone knows how to change that ?

Thanks!

Sk4mi

Comment: Nice work so far! I'm not sure what effect this country code field is supposed to have, I would expect you to select the keyboard layout in the host OS. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks :)
Yes my host is config in azerty mode... I think it's a parameter to change on the HID configuration itself, but no way to find which :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like dmitry say it, it was just tho wrong mapping for azerty.
I code little python script to send the right code!
Each character got two values, first one use for decimal of modifier key value (like <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> ) and second is the decimal of key pressed.

```
 azerty_hid_codes = {
    'a' : (0, 20), 'b' : (0, 5), 'c' : (0, 6),
    'd' : (0, 7), 'e' : (0, 8), 'f' : (0, 9),
    'g' : (0, 10), 'h' : (0, 11), 'i' : (0, 12),
    'j' : (0, 13), 'k' : (0, 14), 'l' : (0, 15),
    'm' : (0, 51), 'n' : (0, 17), 'o' : (0, 18),
    'p' : (0, 19), 'q' : (0, 4), 'r' : (0, 21),
    's' : (0, 22), 't' : (0, 23), 'u' : (0, 24),
    'v' : (0, 25), 'w' : (0, 29), 'x' : (0, 27),
    'y' : (0, 28), 'z' : (0, 26), '1' : (2, 30),
    '2' : (2, 31), '3' : (2, 32), '4' : (2, 33),
    '5' : (2, 34), '6' : (2, 35), '7' : (2, 36),
    '8' : (2, 37), '9' : (2, 38), '0' : (2, 39),
    '\n': (0, 40), '\b': (0, 42), '\t': (0, 43),
    ' ' : (0, 44), '-' : (0, 35), '=' : (0, 46),
    '[' : (64, 34), ']' : (64, 45), '\\': (64, 37),
    ';' : (0, 54), '\'': (64, 33), '`' : (64, 36),
    ',' : (0, 16), ':' : (0, 55), '/' : (2, 55),
    'A' : (2, 20), 'B' : (2, 5), 'C' : (2, 6),
    'D' : (2, 7), 'E' : (2, 8), 'F' : (2, 9),
    'G' : (2, 10), 'H' : (2, 11), 'I' : (2, 12),
    'J' : (2, 13), 'K' : (2, 14), 'L' : (2, 15),
    'M' : (2, 51), 'N' : (2, 17), 'O' : (2, 18),
    'P' : (2, 19), 'Q' : (2, 4), 'R' : (2, 21),
    'S' : (2, 22), 'T' : (2, 23), 'U' : (2, 24),
    'V' : (2, 25), 'W' : (2, 29), 'X' : (2, 27),
    'Y' : (2, 28), 'Z' : (2, 26), '!' : (0, 56),
    '@' : (64, 39), '#' : (64, 32), '$' : (0, 48),
    '%' : (32, 52), '^' : (64, 38), '&' : (0, 30),
    '*' : (0, 49), '(' : (0, 34), ')' : (0, 45),
    '_' : (0, 37), '+' : (2, 46), '{' : (64, 33),
    '}' : (64, 46), '|' : (64, 35), '.' : (2, 54),
    '"' : (0, 32), '~' : (64, 31), '<' : (0, 100),
    '>' : (2, 100), '?' : (2, 16) }
```

This list can be enriched there aren't all keys but minimal for HID attack !
And now to send character i use struct library, to encode data in good format on usb bus.

```
import struct
modif, key = azerty_hid_codes[wantedChar]
raw = struct.pack("BBBBL", modif, 0x00, key, 0x00, 0x00000000)
with open("/dev/hidg0", "wb") as f:
    f.write(raw) # press key
    f.write(struct.pack("Q", 0)) # release key
```

Answer (score 2):

Scan codes identify physical keys on the keyboard, not characters. Since your host is in AZERTY mode (where <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Q</kbd> are swapped), sending a scancode corresponding to `A` results in `Q` being typed. This is by design.

The comment in your tutorial is misleading. This line

```
echo -ne "\0\0\x4\0\0\0\0\0" > /dev/hidg0 #press a
```

is not pressing <kbd>A</kbd>, it presses the key number 4, which corresponds to `A` in [en-US layout](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-14.html). Your layout is different, so you get a different character for the same key.

PS. If you need a quick hack to convert strings between QWERTY and AZERTY layouts in your scripts, that would be:

```
$ echo qwerty AZERTY | tr qwazQWAZ azqwAZQW
azerty QWERTY
```

Comment: I've followed your idea and i managed to make it works!
I use python to send to /dev/hidg0, i'll post how to that works.

I use my keyboard and wireshark to capture scan codes for azerty, and i report it in python to make my mapping works, thank you for the help ;)